# Generating items in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, scene

I have a code for generating card items to the Qt scene. This is what I came up with so far. The member functions called are just what you would derive from the name, so I don't need to include them here.

```
// creating the cards
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int line_brake = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        card = new Card();
        int card_width = card->getWidth();
        int card_height = card->getHeight();
        if(j == (width-1))
        {
            line_brake = 1;
        }
        else if((j != (width-1)) && (line_brake == 1))
        {
            y += card_height;
            card->setPos(x,y);
            line_brake = 0;
            x = 0 - card_width;
        }
        else
        {
            card->setPos(x,y);
            x += card_width;
        }
        scene->addItem(card);
    }
}
```

This is how my scene looks after this code runs:

[image: The scene]

What might be the problem? I need the cards to be layed out in a 7*7 square. That means 7 rows, 7 columns and in each field a card image.

---

This is how my scene looks after edit suggestions by @molbdnilo:

[image: The scene after edits]

```
// creating the cards
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int line_brake = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        card = new Card();
        int card_width = card->getWidth();
        int card_height = card->getHeight();
        if(j == (width-1))
        {
            line_brake = 1;
            continue;
        }
        else if((j != (width-1)) && (line_brake == 1))
        {
            y += card_height;
            card->setPos(x,y);
            line_brake = 0;
            x = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            card->setPos(x,y);
            x += card_width;
        }
        scene->addItem(card);
    }
}
```

Comment: When `j` is `width - 1`, you're adding a card that hasn't had its position set.

Comment: I suspect you meant to use `height` instead of `width` in the outer loop header.

Comment: @molbdnilo I added a `continue;` in there, but the problem is still there.

Comment: @Wintermute the `width` variable is the width of the board, and that is always width*width. So no height.

Comment: @user3710031 Perhaps you could add a description of what you expect the scene to look like? I suspect that `x = 0 - card_width` causes you to place cards outside the window.

Comment: @molbdnilo I added the description. (I need the cards to be layed out in a 7*7 square. That means 7 rows, 7 columns and in each field a card image.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know why this code makes problems. I also don't know why it is written in such a complex way. To generate the cards I would do the following:

```
const int size = 7;
for(int row = 0; row < size; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < size; col++)
    {
        Card *card = new Card;
        int card_width = card->getWidth();
        int card_height = card->getHeight();
        int x = col * card_width;
        int y = row * card_height;
        card->setPos(x, y);
        scene->addItem(card);
    }
}
```

Even more. According to the picture, it looks like all cards have the same dimensions, so I would take both `card_width` and `card_height` out for the loops and make them constant values.

Comment: This works perfectly. You're right, but the dimensions of the cards can change and I thought it good practice to make the dimensions a member of the Card class.

Comment: @user3710031, that was, indeed, good idea. Will the dimensions change dynamically (at run-time), or you will change it latter, during your cards design?

Comment: @vanacho I define them during development, when I might change the image dimensions, so they're hardcoded. no runtime changes.

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete the answer vahancho gave you. When you encounter a problem like this, just take a pen and a paper and write step by step your variables values. It's very simple and you can figure out what the problem is.

---

Start with:

- x = 0
- y = 0
- line_brake = 0
- width = 7
- Considering card's width and height = 1

---

Start looping:

- i = 0, j = 0 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(0,0), next x=1 (**card A**)
- i = 0, j = 1 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(1,0), next x=2 (**card B**)
- i = 0, j = 2 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(2,0), next x=3 (**card C**)
- i = 0, j = 3 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(3,0), next x=4 (**card D**)
- i = 0, j = 4 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(4,0), next x=5 (**card E**)
- i = 0, j = 5 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(5,0), next x=6 (**card F**)
- i = 0, j = 6 --> going in 1st condition, no setPos(), see default x,y value in card constructor ?, card added probably in 0,0, line_break=1 (**card G**)
- i = 1, j = 0 --> going in 2nd condition, y=1, card->setPos(6, 1), line_break=0, next x=-1 (**card H**)
- i = 1, j = 1 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(-1, 1), next x=0 (**card I**)
- i = 1, j = 2 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(0, 1), next x=1 (**card J**)
- i = 1, j = 3 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(1, 1), next x=2 (**card K**)
- i = 1, j = 4 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(2, 1), next x=3 (**card L**)
- i = 1, j = 5 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(3, 1), next x=4 (**card M**)
- i = 1, j = 6 --> going in 1st condition, no setPos(), see default x,y value in card constructor ?, card added probably in 0,0, line_break=1 (**card N**)
- i = 2, j = 0 --> going in 2nd condition, y=2, card->setPos(4, 2), line_break=0, next x=-1 (**card O**)
- i = 2, j = 1 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(-1, 2), next x=0 (**card P**)
- i = 2, j = 2 --> going in 3rd condition, card->setPos(0, 2), next x=0 (**card Q**)
- i = 2, j = 3 --> ...
- i = 2, j = 4 --> ...

As the results:

[image]

Comment: wow, great explanation! i will definitely use my pen and pencil more :)